# How can we get iCloud image/media url for an iCloud account using any api?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, icloud, photo-gallery

How can we access user's iCloud Photo Library from CloudKit Web API?

We want to implement a feature in our iOS app, where by logging user to it's iCloud account inside the application, we can use the access token or any other mechanism to get access of all media/image files on his iCloud from our server.

Comment: use CloudKit JS
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKitJS/Reference/CloudKitJavaScriptReference/index.html

Comment: It will give only access to public records stored under specific app, But we need access all the media-gallery/photos on the server side like we can access them on device by Apple given Photos Framework.

Comment: Yes you can fetch photo and video please look here https://www.npmjs.com/package/icloud-api .